# postgresql Переименование связанных таблиц

Tags: postgresql

postgresql считается лучшей SQL БД.
Мне стало интересно, почему при переименовании таблицы командой `ALTER TABLE producr rename to product;` не переименовываются так-же связанные таблицы (таблицы которые были созданы автоматически). Пример всего списка

```
postgres=# \d
               List of relations
 Schema |      Name       |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+-----------------+----------+----------
 public | customer        | table    | postgres
 public | customer_id_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | producr         | table    | postgres
 public | producr_id_seq  | sequence | postgres
(4 rows) Опечатка в 3 табилце. Последняя таблица создана автоматически.
```

Из следующего кода видим, что автоматические связанные таблицы переименованы не были. Хорошо, что она 1, а если бы их было 10?

```
postgres=# ALTER TABLE producr rename to product;
ALTER TABLE
postgres=# \d
               List of relations
 Schema |      Name       |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+-----------------+----------+----------
 public | customer        | table    | postgres
 public | customer_id_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | producr_id_seq  | sequence | postgres
 public | product         | table    | postgres
(4 rows)
```

В этом есть какая-то причина,
**Может я не ту команду ввел?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что это не «связанная таблица»,
а всего лишь последовательность, которая хоть
и создавалась вместе с таблицей, является почти независимым
объектом БД. Либо переименовывайте
последовательность отдельно:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE producr_id_seq RENAME TO product_id_seq;
```

Либо модернизируйте свой код
и используйте генерацию:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
)
;
```

```
                            Table "public.product"
 Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id     | bigint |           | not null | generated by default as identity
```

И никаких последовательностей.